# converting sql time to asp.net datetime

Tags: sql, asp.net, datetime, time

i'm trying to convert the time that i get from a sql database to datetime in asp.net. the column type in the database is `time(7)`, the column is named `"vertrek_uur"`, i have tried this code, but it throws an applicationException

```
vertrek_uur = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["vertrek_uur"]))
```

**Sample Time:**

Time is Stored in Databas like this `10:00:00,0000000`

**Goal:**

I want to parse it like `10:00`

Comment: What's the desired result and sample data? You can also use DateTime.Parse / DateTime.TryParse (depending on whether you want to do something if it fails)

Comment: you can cast time from datetime but you can't convert time to date time

Comment: the time in the database is stored as 10:00:00,0000000 for 10am. i'm trying to parse it into a usable DateTime, like 10:00, if that's possible.

how could i do it otherwise?

Comment: You can use the reader's GetDateTime method and then use it like any other DateTime https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

i know there is lots of way to get this anyhow this is one

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    string a ="10:00:00,0000000";
    string b = a.Substring(0,5);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

**Output: 10:00**